# Evitar separación de palabras mediante guion en R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

¿cómo puedo evitar que, al renderizar un R Markdown a PDF, se separen las palabras con guiones cuando no caben en una línea? (no puedo usar salto de línea porque entonces la justificación de texto no funciona) Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenida Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: En caso, el silabeo automático no sea el correcto, podrías usar el comando ` \- `,  por ejemplo: ar\-chi\-pié\-la\-go.  agrega un ejemplo para entender mejor lo que deseas realizar.

Answer (score 0):

## Se necesita dos cosas:

1. R package Styler
2. latex
   \usepackage{fvextra}

## Se hace como así

En el parte *YAML* de su **.Rmd**:

````
header-includes:
  - |
    ```{=latex}
    \usepackage{fvextra}
    \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{
      breaksymbolleft={}, 
      showspaces = false,
      showtabs = false,
      breaklines,
      commandchars=\\\{\}
    }
    ```
---
````

En un *chunk*:

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy="styler")
```
````

Por ejemplo, está aquí **separacion.Rmd**:

````
---
title: "Evitar separación de palabras mediante guion en R Markdown"
output:
  pdf_document:
  latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
  - |
    ```{=latex}
    \usepackage{fvextra}
    \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{
      breaksymbolleft={}, 
      showspaces = false,
      showtabs = false,
      breaklines,
      commandchars=\\\{\}
    }
    ```
---
````

````
```{r, muchas_muchas_palabras, eval=FALSE,echo=FALSE}
# --- 1. ---
A<-1234.78;B<-function(f){return(f)};X[[1]]<-model.matrix(~m$groups[[n.levels-i+1]]-1,contrasts.arg=c("contr.treatment","contr.treatment"))

# --- 2. ---
PP2     <-         ggplot(    data = P2, aes( dm ))         +     geom_point(  aes( y  = dm ), show.legend  =  FALSE  )

# --- 3. ---
vinhos <- vinhos_raw %>% mutate(quality = if_else(condition = quality >=5, true = "bom", false = "ruim"), quality = as.factor(quality)) %>% select(quality, everything())
```

# El Problema

¿Cómo puedo evitar que, al renderizar un R Markdown a PDF, se separen las palabras con guiones cuando no caben en una línea? Por ejemplo:

```{r,eval=FALSE}
<<muchas_muchas_palabras>>
```

# La Solución -- `Styler`

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy="styler")    # Si falta 'styler': there is no package called 'styler'  --->  install.packages("styler")
```

```{r,eval=FALSE}
<<muchas_muchas_palabras>>
```

1. **Wrap code**  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222203/rmarkdown-wrap-code-in-chunks-but-keep-breaks-after-pipe

2. **Styler**  
https://styler.r-lib.org
````

## Resultado

[image: pdf con resultado]

## Referencias:

1. **Wrap code**
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222203/rmarkdown-wrap-code-in-chunks-but-keep-breaks-after-pipe
2. **Styler**
   https://styler.r-lib.org

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, pero en mi caso no me ha solucionado el problema. Al renderizar a PDF me sigue separando las últimas palabras de cada fila por un guion cuando esta no cabe en dicha linea.